# show that $L_p(X)$ satisfies $C(s)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. For simple functions
$$
f(\omega)=
\begin{cases}
x_1, \text{ if } \omega \in A_1,\\
\vdots \\
x_n, \text{ if } \omega \in A_n,\\
\end{cases},
$$
define
$$\|f\|_{L_p(X)} = \left( \sum_j \mu(A_j)\|x_j\|^p \right)^{1/p}$$
provided the $A_j$s are disjoint. In general,
$$\|f\|_{L_p(X)} = \left( \int \|f(\omega)\|^p_X \mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p}$$
for all $f$ in the closure of simple functions. The completion is denoted by $L_p(X)$, which is a Banach space.

Let $s \leq p \leq s'$ and $s  \leq 2$. A Banach space $X$ satisfies $C(s)$ if
$$(\|x+y\|_X^r +\|x-y\|_X^r)^{1/r} \leq 2^{1-1/s}(\|x\|_X^s + \|y\|_X^s)^{1/s}$$
for $r = s'$.
Show that $L_p(X)$ satisfies $C(s)$.

I was able to show that $(\|f+g\|_{L_p(X)}^{s'} + \|f-g\|_{L_p(X)}^{s'})^{1/s'} \leq 2(\|f\|_{L_p(X)}^{s'} + \|g \|_{L_p(X)}^{s'})^{1/s'}$ applying $|a+b|^p \leq 2^p ( |a|^p +|b|^p )$ for $p \geq 0$ and the tighter bound $|a+b|^p \leq 2^{p-1} ( |a|^p +|b|^p )$ for $p \geq 1$ repeatedly, but not the above bound. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: seems like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson%27s_inequalities could be applied

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That looks useful.

Comment: I'm not able to apply Clarkson's inequality here because there is no relation between $p$ and $s$ except that $p \leq s'$. Any other ideas?